# how to create app for windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

i am new in in phone app developing . but i dont know which is best way to create windows phone app

Phone Gap or windows sdk(in visual studio) use to create this app?

Comment: If you want to work on windows phone 8.1 development I would advise Visual Studio. Make sure you select the custom install and select the windows 8.1 dev tools if you plan to use Visual Studio 15. Secondly if you want to just make this one app and don't have a lot of experience coding, you could use App Studio.

Comment: I think i unable to create this application in app studio. I have visual studio and i am .net developer so i need to create this application in vs. but i dont know about it that how to create this app. i means what knowlege i need to know before i need to create this application. and Its possible to create this application